# CodeIgniter subfolders and URI routing

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I’ve read the manual on URI routing and views and something is not clicking with me.

In my views folder, I have a subfolder called products. In there is a file called product_view.  In my controller, I have:

```
function index() {
            $data['title'] = 'Product Overview';
            $data['main_content'] = 'products/product_view';
            $this->load->view('templates/main.php', $data);
        }
```

The template loads a header view, a footer view and a navigation view, plus the view as a main content variable.

In my URI routing, I have:

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI ROUTING
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you re-map URI requests to specific controller functions.
|
| Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string
| and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a
| URL normally follow this pattern:
|
|   example.com/class/method/id/
|
| In some instances, however, you may want to remap this relationship
| so that a different class/function is called than the one
| corresponding to the URL.
|
| Please see the user guide for complete details:
|
|   http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
|
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RESERVED ROUTES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| There are two reserved routes:
|
|   $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
|
| This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the
| URI contains no data. In the above example, the "welcome" class
| would be loaded.
|
|   $route['scaffolding_trigger'] = 'scaffolding';
|
| This route lets you set a "secret" word that will trigger the
| scaffolding feature for added security. Note: Scaffolding must be
| enabled in the controller in which you intend to use it.   The reserved 
| routes must come before any wildcard or regular expression routes.
|
*/

$route['default_controller'] = "index_controller";
$route['laser-configurator'] = "configurator";
$route['news-and-events'] = "news";
$route['products/product-overview'] = "products/product_view";
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";


/* End of file routes.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/config/routes.php */
```

This causes a 404 error when I try to go to domain.com/products/product-overview.  Do I need to do something with my .htaccess?  If so, what?  Here is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I’d appreciate some specific help, as the documentation isn’t specific on how to address this.  I’ve done a little searching in the forums, and didn’t see anything, but I’m posting this while I keep looking.

Comment: can you post full contents of your route file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use multi-level directory structure for your controllers use router extention talked about in [this post](http://glennpratama.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/multi-level-subfolder-for-controller-in-codeigniter/), I have used it on occasion, and can vouch for it working.

Comment: Got it.  Do I just upload it and go, or do I need to call it somehow?

Comment: if you have named it correctly as the post instructs, you should be able to upload and go.

Comment: umm...  you know you marked a different answer as correct right?

Comment: That was before your comment.  It ultimately wasn't what I wanted.

Comment: If I want to load a view in a subfolder, but as $data['main_content'], do I do something other than 'products/file-name', because that doesn't work.  (It's so I can use a template in my $this->load->view('templates/main.php', $data)

Comment: probably would need to be a seperate question, make one, fully give your controller code, and templaets/main.php code and I'll take a look, maybe just post a link here.

Answer (score 2):

In CI URIs are routed by the name of your controller and the name of the method in the controller.

If the controller is named "products.php" the function for the corresponding view is called "index", the correct URI for that page is "/products".

So your code should be

```
$route['products/product-overview'] = 'products/index';
```

Comment: So how do I use subfolders for my controllers and views if I follow this?